# How to implement login in angular js:binding and input value to the REST API URL?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to input a username and password into the input fields and send them to the API URL to authenticate the user and return data. I can provide hardcoded credentials to the URL and successfully login. But what I need is to able to input values in the Web interface dynamically and perform the login.

I have no idea how to bind input values into the URL and how the format should be written. Please help with this.

My controller with hard-coded username and password:

```
var login = angular.module('login', []);
    login.controller('loginController',       ['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.loginauth = function(username,password)
     {
           $http({
           method  : 'POST',
           url     : 'http://televisionarybackendservices.azurewebsites.net/auth/login?username=Evangeli&password=1234',
           headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          })
          .success(function(data) {
               console.log(data)
              $scope.userData = data;

        });
     };
```

`enter code here`}]);

My html modal to log in;

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ue">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ue" placeholder="" ng-model="username">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="" ng-model="password">
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="loginauth(username,password)">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <div ng-repeat="data in userData">
                        {{data.username}}<br />
                        {{data.created_at}}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I need to enter username and password dynamically and not supply hard-coded values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited the grammar and structure to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the answer.This is for anyone who need help.

```
  var login = angular.module('login', []);
    login.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.loginauth = function(username,password)
     {
           $http({
           method  : 'POST',
           url     : 'http://televisionarybackendservices.azurewebsites.net/auth/login',
            data: jQuery.param({
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
                 }),
           headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          })
          .success(function(data) {
               console.log(data)
              $scope.userData = data;

        });
     };
```

}]);